# Declare string type for parameter in LLVM

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, language-design

How would I declare a string parameter in the [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) C++ API? For example, to declare a `double` parameter, I would do this:

```
argTypes.push_back(Type::getDoubleTy(*context))
```

Is it possible to do this for a string? I understand that a string is an array of i8, but I just need to know the correct function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, a string can be represented as a pointer to an array of i8 elements, so, for representing a string parameter, you would generally use i8* because parameters are typically pointers to some data:

```cpp
argTypes.push_back(Type::getInt8PtrTy(*context));
```

Remember that this representation assumes that your strings are null-terminated (C strings). If you want to pass strings that also contain their length (C++ std::string wise), you'd usually pass a struct that contains both a pointer to the data (i8*) and the length (i64 or some other integer type).